# how to change value in inspector during run time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

here is a kid asking for help !

i want to change the values of particular game object in inspector , during run time ,
got stucked totally .......

here all guns using single script GUN CONTROLLER , there is a variable for damage enemy called "damage" so in every guns having different damage value in inspector so that big gun can make big damage , if i want to upgrade gun by improving damage count for particular gun from upgrade panel in main menu , it affects all the guns because they are sharing same script , what should i do its annoying because i try multiple way to to make this think work but, it make me tired .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGGNT.jpg)
above image is main menu here you can see bottom buttons control above images , to see gun features , and upgrade

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGgWM.jpg)
its a snap of hierarchy where i am switching between guns during runtime

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldNWy.jpg)
gun controller script snap share by the all guns !

Comment: I see you have "Damage" variable attached to the GunController. I guess this is a single script and all guns share this script. I'd make a "Gun" script, attach this to every Gun game object and make a "Damage" field. This way every gun will have its own damage and you can alter this variable anytime and will be used only by this game object (gun). 

I hope I understood your issue correctly.

Comment: @rootpanthera ,yes you got the point as i wanted , i have around 7 guns all sharing single script , but same script attached to all guns separately for ex-  scene mode  user having pistol so there damage count will be 10 , if he switch to machine gun  here damage count will be 40, here in scene mode i manuallly assigned the damage count value to particular gun , so different gun making different damage , it works fine , but the problem is if i want to give functionality  to user to change the damage count by upgrading gun  i tried with static varible , but it affect all the guns damage counts!

Comment: @rootpanthera i also attached the images , check it you will understand :(

Comment: So you don't have the separate script for guns? I think it won't be pretty without making a separate script for guns only. There you could easily upgrade each gun. And the meaning behind the "static" keyword is that all objects will share this variable, so it makes sense that it affects all the guns.

Comment: @rootpanthera yes you are right , that's why i need to change the damage count from inspector when user upgrade the gun :( , i am making this game for mobile so if i create separate script for each gun it will make extra load ...

Comment: @rootpanthera so what else i can do , if i don't want to create separate script for each gun !

Comment: This "extra load" is unnoticeable, Unity can easily handle this without any issues, so don't be afraid to create extra scripts just for that.

Comment: @rootpanthera but if i changed the script it i have to make so many changes  in different scripts , it will make everything messy wright now whole game has to deal with only gun- controller script  but after making it multiple ... i don't know what will happen .... :D

Comment: @rootpanthera thanks for the quick reply ! but basic code was created by someone else  ..